# Moving internal memory to external sd card

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

My phones internal memory is full, how do i move it to my secure digital card? How can i get

my files

off my secure digital card if i took it out wrong, I did a factory reset?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a file explorer to move files from internal memory to secure memory card.

You can download file explorers for free from play store. ES file explorer is a great one for example.

You can then cut and paste your downloads, media files, documents to your sd card. Your internal memory is displayed as sdcard0 and your external sdcard is displayed as sdcard1. They both will be present in /storage folder.

If you want to move app data to external sdcard, you need specialised application. Many such applications would need root access to function. Link to sd is a great app for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could just connect his phone to the computer and cut paste all the files from your internal sd card to your external secure sd